# OneSignal Unsubscribe User on certain condition when App Starts

Tags: android, onesignal

Our App used Parse.com before, and now we are implementing OneSignal. Unfortunately we lost the user data from Parse, but would prefer to not bother users that already opted out.

Opting out is done through a simple toggle and the state is saved. My idea was to read that state, and then run OneSignal.setSubscription(false); when the App is opened and the user gets registered with OneSignal (or is already registered) so he gets unsubscribed because of the previously saved toggle.

However, OneSignal doesn't do anything on the Server side even though while debugging the code inside the if statement gets executed while launching the App from Android Studio on my Phone.

OneSignal registers my device and sets subscriptions to yes but doesn't unsubscribe if following code is executed:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("prefpush", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Boolean checkSub = prefs.getBoolean("prefpush", false);
    if(!checkSub) {
        OneSignal.setSubscription(false);
    }
```

This part also returns "false" while debugging even though my device is visible, subscribed and can receive notifications:

```
status.getSubscriptionStatus().getSubscribed();
```

The OneSignal part that initialises Push Notifications:

```
        OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
            .setNotificationReceivedHandler( new ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler() )
            .init();
```

I would implement another case, that is, to check if the user is subscribed in the first place but has notifications disabled inside the app (check if the toggle is disabled), so OneSignal.setSubscription(false); isn't executed constantly. But I am unable to get it to work in a more simple scenario in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to subscribe or unsubscribe users other than through a toggle (didn't manage to make it work while just launching the app)

My alternative solution is to simply block the Notification from appearing if an user is subscribed but has notifications turned off in settings. This can be done with Onesignals NotificationExtenderService

```
public class NotificationCheck extends NotificationExtenderService {
@Override
protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

    if (prefs.getBoolean("prefpush", true)) {
        return false;
    } else { return true; }
}
```